# Composer update - website stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I updated the Composer using cmd window and got these errors:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Darryldecode\Cart\CartServiceProvider' not found


Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned    with an error


[RuntimeException]
Error Output:
```

The website is not online yet, and I'm running it using xampp.
Now, when i'm trying to access my web site through localhost, I get this error:

FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Darryldecode\Cart\CartServiceProvider' not found.

In the app.php file I have:

```
Darryldecode\Cart\CartServiceProvider::class,
```

in the Application Service Providers, and:

```
'Cart'      => Darryldecode\Cart\Facades\CartFacade::class,
```

in the aliases.

Any ideas on how to get the website back?

Thanks!

Comment: First: check if the file exist!
Then: if not check if you add entry to `composer.json`
And finally: comment this line `Darryldecode\Cart\CartServiceProvider::class,` and run `composer update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tty this steps
Temporary remove

```
Darryldecode\Cart\CartServiceProvider::class,
```

And

```
'Cart'      => Darryldecode\Cart\Facades\CartFacade::class,
```

Type command

```
composer update
```

And then add this class
Because when you update composer he try to find this path before adding in your project, After updating your composer this class added in your folder